# Elastic Search Groovy update Error

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I am getting an error with Groovy script.

```
{"script":"if (ctx._source.containsKey(\"productoption\")) {ctx._source.productoption= [product];} else {ctx._source.productoption= [product];}","params":"{\"product\":[{\"id\":\"123ab\",\"name\":\"testing\"}]}"}
```

Error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason": "[ESMasterNode][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "failed to execute script",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "script_exception",
      "reason": "failed to run inline script [if (ctx._source.containsKey(\"productoption\")) {ctx._source.productoption= [product];} else {ctx._source.productoption= [product];}] using lang [groovy]",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "missing_property_exception",
        "reason": "No such property: product for class: 3b2894bb604d8fb601b627ert64e3fde8242f1b2"
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

It somehow not identifying the param which sent with this. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a little mistake while passing `params`.
Use it like this and you are good to go:

```
{
"script":"if (ctx._source.containsKey(\"productoption\")) {ctx._source.productoption= [product];} else {ctx._source.productoption= [product];}",
"params": {
  "product": [
     {
        "id": "123ab",
        "name": "testing"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was it I was using a Json Serializer on a serialized field.

Comment: Adding to that the productoption is now updating with two square `brackets. "productoption":[ [
     {
        "id": "123ab",
        "name": "testing"
      }
    ]]` Any Idea, how to solve this?

Comment: Remove `[]` from `script`.

Comment: Should not get that. The only condition is that it should be a valid json. Try removing `[]` from `params`.

Comment: Yes it worked if I remove it from Script, Initially i removed it from both Script and params. Thanks.